# How to construct an explicit homotopy equivalence between these classifying spaces?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles, classifying-spaces

Let $E \to G$ be the tautological bundle of $n$-planes, and let $p : Fl(E) \to G$ be the bundle of complete flags in $E$. Tautologically, the pullback $p^\star E \to Fl(E)$ is the universal vector bundle of rank $n$ with a choice of complete flag.

On the other hand, since short exact sequences of vector bundles over paracompact spaces always split, the isomorphism type of a complete flag can be recovered from its line bundle quotients. Therefore, the $n$-fold product of projective spaces $(\mathbb P^\infty)^n$ also classifies vector bundles of rank $n$ with a choice of complete flag.

How can I construct an explicit homotopy equivalence between $Fl(E)$ and $(\mathbb P^\infty)^n$?

Comment: After choosing an identification $(\mathbb{R}^\infty)^n \cong \mathbb{R}^\infty$, the map $(\mathbb{P}^\infty)^n \to \operatorname{Fl}(E)$ is given by $(\ell_1, \ell_2, \dots, \ell_n) \mapsto (\ell_1 \subset \ell_1 \oplus \ell_2 \subset  \dotsb \subset \ell_1 \oplus \ell_2 \oplus \dotsm \oplus \ell_n)$.